# Dividing columns of a data frame group-wise?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, data-manipulation

I have a df:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'Y': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
                    'Z': [10, 5, 6, np.nan, 12],
                                        })
```

I set Y as index and then calculate counts and size group-wise:

```
temp.sort('Y', inplace=True)
temp.set_index('Y', inplace=True, drop=False)
temp.sort_index( inplace=True)

temp['n_obs'] = temp.groupby(by='Y')['Z'].transform('size')
temp['valid'] = temp.groupby(by='Y')['Z'].transform('count')
```

This yields:

```
   Y     Z  n_obs  valid
Y                       
A  A  10.0    2.0    1.0
A  A   NaN    2.0    1.0
B  B   5.0    3.0    3.0
B  B   6.0    3.0    3.0
B  B  12.0    3.0    3.0
```

Now, I want to divide valid by n-obs group-wise:

```
temp['New']=temp.groupby(by='Y').apply(lambda x: (x['valid'] / x['n_obs']))
```

But I get this error:

```
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

Solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use twice [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
temp.sort_values('Y', inplace=True)
temp.set_index('Y', inplace=True, drop=False)
temp.sort_index( inplace=True)

temp['n_obs'] = temp.groupby(by='Y')['Z'].transform('size')
temp['valid'] = temp.groupby(by='Y')['Z'].transform('count')

temp.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

temp['New'] = temp.groupby(by='Y')
                  .apply(lambda x: (x['valid'] / x['n_obs']))
                  .reset_index(drop=True, level=0)
print (temp) 
   Y     Z  n_obs  valid  New
0  A  10.0    2.0    1.0  0.5
1  A   NaN    2.0    1.0  0.5
2  B   5.0    3.0    3.0  1.0
3  B   6.0    3.0    3.0  1.0
4  B  12.0    3.0    3.0  1.0
```

But it seems result is same if omit `groupby` and divide columns only:

```
temp.sort_values('Y', inplace=True)
temp.set_index('Y', inplace=True, drop=False)
temp.sort_index( inplace=True)

temp['n_obs'] = temp.groupby(by='Y')['Z'].transform('size')
temp['valid'] = temp.groupby(by='Y')['Z'].transform('count')


temp['New'] = temp['valid'] / temp['n_obs']
print (temp) 
   Y     Z  n_obs  valid  New
Y                            
A  A  10.0    2.0    1.0  0.5
A  A   NaN    2.0    1.0  0.5
B  B   5.0    3.0    3.0  1.0
B  B   6.0    3.0    3.0  1.0
B  B  12.0    3.0    3.0  1.0
```